# Layering an Image slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, slideshow

I have a div containing jQuery image slideshow, i want to put another div/layer on top of the slideshow. Is it possible? Is it as simple as setting both div z-index css property?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#SlideShow { display: none; width: 868px; height: 296px; }
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.cj-simple-slideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function() {
   $(document).ready(function() {

      //initialize the first slideshow container
      $("#SlideShow").cjSimpleSlideShow();

   });

});
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><div class="header_top"><div class="header_logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="120" height="148" border="0" /></div>
      <div class="header_text"><img src="images/header_text.png" alt="" width="573" height="84" border="0" /></div>
        </div>
      <div class="header_image" style="z-index:0;"><div id="SlideShow" style="display:none;">
         <img src="images/header_image.jpg" width="868" height="296" alt="This is caption 1." /><br />
         <img src="images/header_image1.jpg" width="868" height="296" alt="This is caption 2." /><br />
         <img src="images/header_image2.jpg" width="868" height="296" alt="This is caption 3." /><br />
      </div>
      </div><div class="content">
      <div class="content_inner"><div><img src="images/heading_2.png" alt="Content" /></div>
        <p>Content.</p>
        <p>Content.</p>
        <p>Content.</p></div>
<div class="content_right">
  <div><img src="images/heading_1.png" alt="Content" /></div>
  <p><br />
Content.</p>
  <p>Content.</p>
  <p>Content. </p>
  <p>Content.</p>
  <p>Content<br />
    <br />
  </p>
  </div><br />
<div class="content_service"><div><img src="images/heading_3.png" alt="Content" /></div> 
  </div>
      </div>
</td>
    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want half of 'content_right' div lay on top of slideshow div

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the `z-index` property, or you could perhaps use `position: absolute;` on the div you want to appear above the slide-show.

```
#top_most_element
{
z-index: 99; /* or whatever, just so long as it's higher than those elements 'below' it */
}
```

Or, to use the `position: absolute;` alternative:

```
#container_element
{
position: relative; /* in order to position the child-element relative to this element, not the window or other parent element */
}

#top_most_element
{
position: absolute;
}

<div id="container_element">

  <div class="slide">...</div>
  <div class="slide">...</div>

  <div id="top_most_element">
    <!-- content to show -->
 </div>

</div>
```

This may, or may not, work though, it depends on what javascript solution you're using to create the slideshow and how it works. If you could post that (the js/jQuery/etc, and the relevant (x)html and css) then we might be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: I've put my code above, how to solve this. Something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually put a div on top of a self-baked jquery slide-show and it works normally in all browsers except for IE6 - IE8.

IE has some kind of weird bug where you have to give a background color to the div on top in order for it to have dimensions. And make it transparent afterward to get rid of the background color...

Also see [my question about that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155854/getting-unordered-list-in-front-of-image-slide-show-in-ie8-ie7-and-probably-ie6).

Comment: Well, first of all I don´t know the slide-show you are using and apart from that you will need to show the relevant css and explain what the problem is.