# Clicking on a div placed over an image in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image which may have some divs over it (specifying certain selections within that image). These divs are supposed to be clickable. Something like that:

```
#divOuter { width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 2px solid #0000FF; position: relative; } 
#divInner { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid #00FF00; position: absolute; cursor: pointer;  top: 20px; left: 20px; }

<div id="divOuter">
    <img src="SomeImage.jpg" />
    <div id="divInner"></div>
</div>

$("#divOuter").click(function() { alert("divOuter"); });
$("#divInner").click(function() { alert("divInner"); });
```

In chrome and FF it works as expected (pointer appears over the div, and clicking it alerts "divInner" and then "divOuter").
However, in IE8 it didn't - I got the same behavior only when hovering/clicking on the inner div borders. When clicking inside that div, only "divOuter" was alerted.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Try giving the image width/height information and you probably need a span in the `#divInner` with size.  Had this problem recently myself.

Comment: Try adding background colours to your `divs` and see if that either makes them clickable, or shows where they're being placed.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to recreate that what is called an 'Image Map'. http://www.webstartcenter.com/howto/imgmap.php

Comment: @David - adding a background color to the inner div did work, but I preferred avoiding that.
@GolezTrol - not exactly, I needed something more dynamic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a hack: add an CHAR like "O" to the inner div, and then give it an enormous font size(depends on the area you want to span over):

```
#divInner { /* ... */; font-size: 1000px; color: transparent; }
```

(Also set "overflow: hidden" I think.)

IE likes there to be something there in the container for the click to affect.  If it's just completely empty, it ignores clicks.

a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cbnk8wrk/1/ (watch in IE!)

Comment: This does address the issue, as the problem is IE needs some content size in the DIV, a span set to the size of the containing DIV is a bit less hacky. ;-)

Comment: Well the problem is that you can't really give a `<span>` any height, because it's an inline element. Thus, you'd still need to fill the span up with something.

Comment: Or use a div instead of a span. You can give a span a height, by assigning display:block style to the span. Making it essentially behave like a div.

Comment: @GolezTroi well he's already *got* a `<div>`!  The problem is that there has to be *something* inside, some sort of "content" that IE believes to be clickable. Another empty `<div>` inside won't solve that problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with an unordered list, see [Getting unordered list in front of image slide-show in IE8, IE7 and probably IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155854/getting-unordered-list-in-front-of-image-slide-show-in-ie8-ie7-and-probably-ie6)

The solution : give the div a background color and make it transparent with a filter.

Comment: That does not work if the "background-color" is "transparent".

Comment: @Pointy check the answer to my question, use a normal background color and an IE filter.

Comment: I had to put a minuscule transparency for @philrabin solution to work:  background: rgba(0,0,0,.01)

Answer (score 2):

Adding an 1x1 px transparent background gif to the div is also working.

```
#divInner { background: url(/images/transparent.gif); }
```