# CSS div overlay unclickable in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, overlay

I've been googling and querying stackoverflow quite a bit but I haven't found this exact problem duplicated anywhere else. It's probably something silly I've forgotten.

What I'm trying to do:

**Making a navigation by pressing the right or the left side of the image by using a two-part overlay. The code worked just as I wanted it in the other browsers and I was happy until I tried it in IE.**

Here's my now slaughtered code. I've removed the right side of the div etc. This does not work for me in Internet Explorer 8 (haven't tried IE 7/9 yet) **unless I either**:

- Set a background-color to .navi_left
- Remove the image in .top
- If i put content into .navi_left the content (for example a text) is clickable, in the other browsers the full div is clickable.

Any of those options will make the .navi_left clickable in IE 8.

The html generated:

```
<div class="image_div_big" style="width:600px;">
<div class="top">
   <img src="../img/20110331-200524-1.jpg" class="image_big" width="600" height="450">
   <div class="navi_left" id="172" style="width:312px;height:474px;"><!--placeholder--></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.image_div_big {float:left;}
.top {position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;}
.navi_left {cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:5;border:1px solid black;}
```

The javascript:

```
    $('.navi_left').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (id != '') {
            window.location = '/index_temp.php?i='+id;
        }
    });
```

**MY SOLUTION:**

I finally agreed that I needed to do as suggested below. However I refused to have an IE-specific stylesheet, so I just did it as this:

```
.navi_left {position:absolute;top:0px;z-index:5;background-color:#fff;-moz-opacity:0;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);}
.navi_right {position:absolute;top:0px;z-index:5;background-color:#fff;-moz-opacity:0;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);}
```

Comment: Your PHP code is irrelevant to the browser's behavior and this question. Please show the HTML and JavaScript that your PHP produces--that the browser sees--instead. (And ideally, create a standalone, pared-down, reproducible test case on http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: "I was happy until I tried it in IE" - This oughta be inscribed on Steve Ballmer's gravestone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155854/getting-unordered-list-in-front-of-image-slide-show-in-ie8-ie7-and-probably-ie6) and in the end resorted to an IE specific stylesheet and just gave the clickable area a background colour and a:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it works.

To put @Jared Farrish's comment in the answer itself; I added the following code to the `head` of my html to address only IE using [conditional comments](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"  href="/styles/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Just in case you're wondering how to do that, [How to Create an IE-Only Stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

Comment: @Jared Farrish Thanks for the addition, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: This is also called a "[conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)".

Comment: @jeroen - No problem. Sometimes it's worth hunting down why IE is not working, but sometimes it can't be fixed or it isn't worth the time. I've used conditionals.

Comment: @Jared Farrish If you want your site to behave in IE6 and up, it´s almost impossible to avoid IE specific style-sheets.

Comment: I finally conceded into accepting this as the answer. However I refused to use an IE-specific stylesheet and set the opacity for all browsers.

Comment: @Mattis You don´t need to set the opacity for all browsers, you just need to set a background colour and the opacity in the IE style-sheet. IE specific stylesheets are hard to avoid if you use css and want to support different versions of IE.

Comment: @jeroen I appreciate your comment, and I don't doubt I will have to use them eventually, but at this point I won't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using `filter`/`-ms-filter` the previous solution of setting a background color and then setting its opacity to 0 will not work for you. Instead you can set your `background-image` to a 2x2 transparent png and continue using your existing `filter`/`-ms-filter`'s with no negative effects.